# Find all the natural numbers such that $Z_n$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_n$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

The task is to Find all the natural numbers such that $Z_n$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_n$.

I am pretty sure that for $n>2$ there is no such isomorphism because $Z_n$ has $n$ elements, while $D_n$ has $2n$ elements.

But for $n=1$ and $n=2$ however I think there is an isomorphism because here the reflections act the same as the rotations.

Any help here?

Comment: There are different conventions about whether $D_n$ has $n$ or $2n$ elements, but @MorganRodgers ' comment is very helpful

Comment: So am I correct here?

Comment: @GabiG:  your argument that $Z_n$ is not isomorphic to $D_n$ for $n>2$ works according to the convention that $D_n$ has $2n$ elements, but not according to the convention that $D_n$ has $n$ elements